# Using stripe connect in development without client id

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, mern

Hi I'm not sure if its a bad question but I've been trying to look for an answer for some time but just couldn't seem to find one. I am building my first personal project using MERN stack and it is a platform that allows sellers to sell their products to users. I found out that stripe connect is very suitable for this purpose but the documentation says that I must register my business in order to be able to use stripe connect. Given that I'm not actually planning to launch this web app, it is merely for my own learning, is there a way that I can still use stripe connect without having to register? help is very much appreciated thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're more than welcome to use all of Stripe's feature's for testing and learning without having to incorporate first. You can sign up and use our all our APIs including our [Connect APIs](https://stripe.com/docs/connect) with test keys:

https://dashboard.stripe.com/register.

A good place to start after signing up is the development quickstart: https://stripe.com/docs/development/quickstart

It might also be worthwhile checking out the many Stripe developer office hours videos available on Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/c/StripeDevelopers/videos

Answer (score 0):

I found out stripe also provides test client id at https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/settings/applications which I can use to integrate stripe connect into my app.